# Wrong Output C Terminal

Tags: c, printing, terminal

I am trying to use Ubuntu terminal to display the users input.  If the user enters "exit" the program should quit.  If the user enters something other then "/dev/pts/1" it should display "Unable to open for writing".  The program keeps printing the else statement no matter what I type in. Help please.

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
FILE *fpt;  
char str[100];
char term[20];
fpt = fopen("/dev/pts/1", "w");

while(1)
{
    printf("Enter the terminal to display in: ");
    scanf("%s", term);
    if(term != "exit");
    {
        if(term == "/dev/pts/1")
        {           
            printf("Enter the text to display: ");
            scanf("%s", str);
            fprintf(fpt,"%s\n", str);       
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Unable to open %s for writing\n", term);
        }
    }
}   

fclose(fpt);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `strcmp`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I properly compare strings in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004237/how-do-i-properly-compare-strings-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`strcmp()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/strcmp.html) to compare strings:

```
#include <string.h>

if (strcmp(term, "/dev/pts/1") == 0) {
    // Strings are equal
}
else {
    // Strings are different.
}
```